# How to use a background image in opengl es

Tags: android, iphone, animation, graphics, opengl-es

I am making a solar system project in OPENGL ES in android with an earth and a sun . I want to add a back ground image with stars in it . please tell me how to put a background image in it....

Answer (score 1):

Probably your background would be an star field, so you need a texture and an object to apply that texture to. Common objects used for this are cubes and spheres. The idea is to draw a very big cube or sphere around the camera (but not that big to fall outside the far plane), and when the camera moves, the *sky dome* does too.

For cubes you need to project the texture using a **sky cube map**. For an sphere you would apply and **sky sphere map**.

For simplicity and speed on OpenGL ES I would go for cubes, look for the keyword *skybox*.

Comment: is there any other way?